# Problema em criar tabela no banco

Tags: mysql

Eu coloquei esses comando para criar a tabela;

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    codigo_condominio BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    codigo_proprietario BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    tipoPessoa VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_condominio) REFERENCES condominio (codigo),
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_proprietario) REFERENCES proprietario (codigo)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

porém está me gerando esse erro

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

qual será o problema?

Comment: Antes de criar essa tabela , vc criou a de condomínio e de proprietário?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você receber essa mensagem de erro use o comando abaixo para ter mais detalhes:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

Os motivos mais comuns ao criar uma chave estrangeira, são que tanto o campo referenciado e o campo de chave estrangeira precisam combinar:

- **Engine**: deve ser a mesma

  - Ex.: `InnoDB`
- **Datatype**: deve ser a mesma e ter o mesmo tamanho.

  - Ex.: `VARCHAR(80)`
- **Collation**: deve ser o mesmo

  - Ex.: `utf8`
- **Unique**: chaves estrangeiras devem se referir ao campo que é único (geralmente privado) na tabela de referência.

Outra causa desse erro é você definir um `SET NULL` tendo algumas das colunas são definidas como `NOT NULL`.

Referência: [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)